# Is there a way to connect all ObjectOutputStream's to one Input stream?

Tags: java, oop, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a `Client` class and a `MessageServer` class that communicates to each other via `Socket`s. And they send `Message` object to each other(Not implemented yet).

The thing is, in my MesageServer class, i have a implementation like this

```
LinkedList<Client> clients = new LinkedList<>();

LinkedList<ObjectOutputStream> outs =  new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<ObjectInputStream> ins = new LinkedList<>();
```

But this approach seems odd and not useful the more i think about it.

I want to get `Message` objects from 1 output stream, because that way, I don't have to iterate through every `OOS` object to find out which client actually put an object in the stream.

Am I wrong? How should I approach?

**MessageServer**

```
public class MessageServer extends Server implements Runnable{

    static LinkedList<Message> messages = new LinkedList<>();

    LinkedList<Client> clients = new LinkedList<>();

    LinkedList<ObjectOutputStream> outs =  new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<ObjectInputStream> ins = new LinkedList<>();

    ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    ExecutorService clientThreads = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public MessageServer() throws IOException {
        super(Vars.MESSAGE_PORT);
    }

    //Accept the connetions to the server
    private class ServerConnection implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

                    //Read Client data then add to the list
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

                    outs.add(out);
                    ins.add(in);

                    Client current = (Client) in.readObject();

                    if(current.getType()) {
                        Provider p = (Provider) current;
                        clients.add(p);
                    }else{
                        Receiver r = (Receiver) current;
                        clients.add(r);
                    }
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MessageServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ServerIO implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run(){

        }
    }

    public void addToMessages(Message message) {
        if (!messages.contains(message)) {
            messages.add(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        threads.execute(new ServerConnection());
        threads.execute(new ServerIO());
    }

}
```

The `Provider` and `Receiver` classes are subclasses of the class `Client`, they are there for future video stream and act the same way for now.

**Message**

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

    private final int maxChar = 250;
    private String content;
    private String timeStamp;

    private Client sender;

    public Message(Client sender, String content, String timeStamp) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.content = content;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
public class Client implements Serializable {

    protected String nickname;
    protected long id;
    protected int key;

    /*
    * True -> Provider
    * False -> Receiver
    */
    protected boolean type;

    // MessageServer
    protected transient ObjectOutputStream msgOut;
    protected transient ObjectInputStream msgIn;
    protected transient Socket messageSocket;

    protected transient Socket videoSocket;


    public Client(String nickname, boolean type){

        this.type = type;
        this.nickname = nickname;
        createid();
        makeConnection();
        key = (int) (Math.random() * 8999) + 1000;
    }

    void makeConnection(){
        try {
            messageSocket = new Socket(Vars.IP, Vars.MESSAGE_PORT);
            //TODO make connection with videoServer
            msgOut = new ObjectOutputStream(messageSocket.getOutputStream());
            msgIn = new ObjectInputStream(messageSocket.getInputStream());

            msgOut.writeObject(this);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't know which client sent the message, how can you reply to the correct client? This is not a good approach. What you should have is a thread that handles each client, and also notes when it disconnects etc. If you want to centralize processing, you can make the threads write the objects to a queue that will be read by one specific thread.

Comment: The `ExecutorService clientThreads` variable is there for that purpose but I don't know how I should approach that and how to see when a client sent a message